# LWC/VF page not opening in Android Mobile devices

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I have created a LWC which works great. This LWC has a "preview" button which when you click, opens a Visualforce page that I created (this also works great). However all this works only on desktop but is not working on an android device. Specifically, the LWC works but when i click the preview button, that VF page is not loading in Android devices properly. Can someone please help me wha I can do to make this work. I am guessing I need to add more code besides the window.open to make this work on android mobile apps. My code is below:

LWC Snippet:

```
<template>
<div>
            <lightning-button label="Back" onclick={goToTwo} ></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button class="preview" label="Preview Document" onclick={Preview}></lightning-button>
        </div>
</template>
```

LWC Js:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import saveAndSend from '@salesforce/apex/docController.saveAndSend';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class docGeneration extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @api accId;
    @track htmlPageUrl;
    @track accName;
    @track accLid;
Preview(event) {
        
        this.htmlPageUrl = '/apex/docHTML';
        
        var i;
        this.htmlPageUrl += "&accountId="+ this.accId;
        this.htmlPageUrl += "&accountName="+ this.accName;
        //sforce.one.navigateToSObject(htmlPageUrl, true);
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: this.htmlPageUrl
            }
        }).then(generatedUrl => { // I think there is something WRONG Here or needs modification
            window.open(generatedUrl, '_self');
        });
    }
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="docController" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js"/>

    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="AccountTabPanel"
    tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
    <apex:tab name="name1" id="tabOne"><apex:include pageName="docBody"/></apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>

    <apex:form > 
        <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand" value="Save for In-Person Signing" action="{!saveAndSend}" onclick="redirect('{!retUrl}');"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        function redirect(sObjectId){
            if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce && sforce.one){
                sforce.one.navigateToSObject(sObjectId, "detail");
            } else {
                window.location.href = sObjectId;
            }
           // window.replace = {!retUrl};
            //sforce.one.navigateToSObject(sObjectId, "detail");

        }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

I can paste the apex code as well, but I dont think that would need any modifications for something like this. Again, the code works fine and functions fine in desktop. Its the VF part is not opening in android for some reason
Thank you

Comment: Do you have "Add Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app." checkbox as selected on the visualforce page?

Comment: Hello @tugce, How would I add that to my vf page? What I pasted above is all I have for the vf. Thank you

Comment: Hello @tugce, I just checked that box. However, when i click on the preview button its still not redirecting and loading to the vf page

Comment: @tugce do you have any solution to this problem?